# Time.zone.parse not converting correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

In my development:

```
str = "Sat Jan 12 2013 14:00:00 GMT-0500"
Time.zone.parse(str).utc
```

Outputs:

```
2013-01-12 19:00:00 UTC
```

In my production (appfog):

```
2013-01-12 14:00:00 UTC
```

How can I make it not ignore the timezone?

Comment: Isn’t that output correct? And what is the difference between it and the prod output? Is the first output development?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, the production system is ignoring that the string already includes the TZ info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Time.zone.parse`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse) is interpreting the time passed as being in the current system timezone, throwing away the time zone information in the string:

```
require 'active_support/all'

`date '+%Z %z'`.strip
#=> "EST -0500"
Time.zone = 'MST'
Time.zone.parse('Fri, 31 Dec 1999 14:00:00 HST -10:00')
#=> Fri, 31 Dec 1999 12:00:00 MST -07:00
```

Note that the parsed time is in MST, as expected, but it has adjusted it two hours back—which is the offset between EST (the system time zone) and MST (ActiveSupport’s `Time.zone`). This may be a bug, though, as removing the timezone “name” works as you expect:

```
Time.zone.parse('Fri, 31 Dec 1999 14:00:00 -10:00')
#=> Fri, 31 Dec 1999 17:00:00 MST -07:00
```

Since you’re just converting to UTC in the end anyway, you probably want to just use [`DateTime.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse):

```
DateTime.parse('Fri, 31 Dec 1999 14:00:00 HST -10:00').utc
#=> Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: hooray, it works! fyi, there is indeed a bug also in Mongoid where Javascript string dates have their timestamp ignored! I had to manually set it to DateTime.parse in my controller to override what the javascript date passed in.

Comment: @K2xL You should report the issue and then post the link here `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the "GMT" bit - it's probably confusing the parser:

```
str = "Sat Jan 12 2013 14:00:00 -0500"
Time.zone.parse(str).utc
```

Comment: How come it doesn't confuse the parser on development mode?

Comment: My guess is you develoment machine has a different timeline setup to production. Ie it's setup to use your local time zone rather that UTC or vice versa